# Problems with deploying fabric for mezzanine

Tags: django, fabric, mezzanine

As I think I understand it, fabric contains this command which is supposed to configure a server for your mezzanine-django project:

```
fab all
```

I get this error:

```
Aborting, no hosts defined.
```

The docs for fabric are confusing for me on this aspect.  I'm not sure where/how to edit this hosts option.

Thanks, friends.

EDIT
Relevant contents of settings.py

```html
# Hosts/domain names that are valid for this site; required if DEBUG is False
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.domain.com','.domain.com.',]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an example of how to set the hosts configuration in the Mezzanine Deployment documentation (http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/deployment.html#configuration)

Comment: I am aware of this information.  In settings.py for the project they are commented out.  It says: 
# These settings are used by the default fabfile.py provided.
# Check fabfile.py for defaults.
Because of this, I'm not sure if I should paste this into fabfile, or just uncomment it in settings.py.  
Also, because the fields look like environment variables, I'm not sure if they need to be defined somewhere else.

Comment: So I've copied this bit of code into local_settings.py.
"HOSTS": ALLOWED_HOSTS ['.mydomain.com'] is returning a ALLOWED_HOSTS not defined error.  Trying to assign the ALLOWED_HOSTS with an equal sign is bad syntax.  Not sure where to go from here

Comment: You need to define ALLOWED_HOSTS prior to the FABRIC dictionary definition: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts

Comment: I updated my post with contents of settings.py.  From the documentation it seems like this is correct.